# Laravel 5: How to run a RAW MySQL statement?

Tags: php, laravel

So I have been moving from framework to framework and one feature that I liked about CodeIgniter over Laravel was that it supplys Raw statements.

I did some research on Laravel and the statements that they can supply and I found the DB::raw($sql) statement.

I tried initially to do the statement like so:

```
$query = DB::raw("SELECT * FROM users WHERE username = 'admin');
foreach ($query as $q) {
  $id = $q['id'];
}
```

but that didnt manage to work, so I did some more research looking at stack overflow questions and I managed to find the structure was a bit different, so I tried:

```
$query = DB::select(DB::raw("SELECT * FROM users WHERE username = 'admin');
```

then used the same foreach loop as I did in the first part to try to loop the data.

If this is the wrong way of using this method please let me know, also, I'm not planning on keeping this method for using raw statements and getting user data, I just am trying to know that is it able to be used.

Comment: Yes, the method is fine.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

use `get()` function :

```
DB::table('users')->select('*')->where('username', '=', 'admin')->get();
```

Comment: I managed to fix the problem and I was trying to use the raw database statement. The issue was just that it would generate a object instead of an associative array as I thought it would.

Comment: @Jek you use DB::raw or selectRaw when you want write a custom select statement